# Text orientation

Tags: c#, wpf, text, alignment, tabitem

I know you can do this to get vertical text in a tab header:

```
<Window x:Class="Abodemploy.Window1"  
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"  
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"  
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">  
    <Grid>  
        <TabControl Margin="0" Name="tabControl1" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" TabStripPlacement="Left">  
            <TabItem>  
                <TabItem.Header>  
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">  
                        <TextBlock>Homes</TextBlock>  
                    </StackPanel>  
                </TabItem.Header>  
                <TabItem.LayoutTransform>  
                <TransformGroup>  
                    <RotateTransform Angle="90" />  
                </TransformGroup>  
                </TabItem.LayoutTransform>  
                <Grid />  
            </TabItem>  
        </TabControl>  
    </Grid>  
</Window>
```

However the text letters are sideways. What I'd like (if possible) is for the letter orientation to be correct (ie upwards), but the text flow downwards, is this possible, or am I just dreaming the impossible dream?

Thanks Psy

Comment: Could you do this by setting the width to a very small number and turning on text wrapping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the following post answers your question:
[vertical-text-in-wpf-textblock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349875/vertical-text-in-wpf-textblock)

and I was able to get the desired result as follows:

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="Test.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl Margin="0" Name="tabControl1" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" TabStripPlacement="Left">
            <TabItem>
                <TabItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock >
                            <ItemsControl x:Name="ic"></ItemsControl>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </TabItem.Header>
                <Grid />
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And then set the ItemsSource of the ItemsControl to the string you want in the code behind.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for a similar question and couldn't find it, then when I was looking for a different issue I came across this answer, and yup, it works

Comment: Had to make a few changes, and now the tab headers are stupidly wide, but its what I needed

Comment: Cool - glad you got it sorted

Answer (score 3):

Do you ask for this?

```
 <TabItem.Header>  
      <StackPanel>  
            <TextBlock>H</TextBlock>  
            <TextBlock>o</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>m</TextBlock>  
            <TextBlock>e</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>s</TextBlock>
      </StackPanel>  
 </TabItem.Header>
```