# Fastest way to add text to canvas dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf

I made a simple chart by putting stack panels on a canvas and then filling the stack panels with lables according to the data given.However I am not very happy with the performance.

If I change the stack panels with listboxes, and instead of lables add strings, would it be faster to render the data? The data I need to show is a subset from a large array of lists of strings. When I move the index, I have to clear all the listboxes and fill them with the new data.
Or is there a faster way to do it?

All my strings are of 4 characters. Is it possible to change the orientation to vertical so that each listbox shows something like this

A

A

A

A

B

B

B

B

C

C

C

C

D

D

D

D

etc... 
The strings are AAAA, BBBB, CCCC, DDDD.

Comment: Are you displaying all of the characters on the screen, or are they scrolling off of the screen?

Answer (score 1):

Just a few things you might want to keep in mind:

1. ListBoxes are a lot more heavy than StackPanels alone, ListBoxes normally contain a StackPanel themselves.
2. ListBoxes are to be used if selection is wanted, if not you'd use an ItemsControl, But ItemsControls are composite controls and hence haevier than a container alone.
3. If you only want text then use TextBlock which is more lightweight than Label. ([TextBlock vs. Label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59099/what-is-the-difference-between-the-wpf-textblock-element-and-label-control))
4. [How to create vertical text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349875/vertical-text-in-wpf-textblock)

Answer (score 1):

I think you would want `ItemsControl`, not `ListBox` (no need for item selection).

The question is whether the overhead is worth it for you. `ItemsControl` is more heavy weight than `StackPanel` (as H.B. said, it often contains a `StackPanel`). The reason to use an `ItemsControl` would be UI virtualization. If many of the items are scrolling off of the screen, `ItemsControl` will usually (not always, depends on the control template) only generate visuals for the ones that are on the screen. This saves a lot of processing time.

If you want raw speed, create a `DrawingVisual`, call `RenderOpen()` on this visual, use the `DrawingContext` to draw the items and then display the `DrawingVisual` inside of the `Canvas`.