#  How do I create a vertical text block without using an ItemsControl?

Tags: wpf

Alright, trying this again. All I want is to rotate a text block, nothing tricky. And I don't want to do it using an ItemsControl because it will require using a control for each and every letter, which is way too expensive for my needs.

[image]

Comment: P.S. And please don't just blindly delete it because I've "got too much reputation" or some other nonesense like that. Seriously, there is no need to act like that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vertical Text in Wpf TextBlock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349875/vertical-text-in-wpf-textblock)

Comment: Bounties *do* get attention to a question even if it has an accepted answer.

Comment: Again, that one uses an ItemsControl. So unless you've got a specific one other than the accepted answer it doesn't help.

Comment: This is a duplicate with a little localization spin on it, the answers on the other question **do not matter**. Just because you don't like the answes does not mean you can create duplicates.

Comment: Tags *do not* belong into the tile.

Comment: Seriously, why are you interfering? You aren't helping me or the community at large by preventing people from asking questions. I shouldn't have to fight to defend such a simple question.

Comment: I am helping the community by keeping it clear of clutter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the controversy if it's a duplicate or not, there may be a way to achieve vertical text on a very low level, involving a [GlyphRun](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms635009%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I haven't tested that in detail, but what i know is, you would have to

1. create a GlyphRun with the IsSideways property set to true, meaning
   all character will be rotated 90° counter-clockwise,
2. get a [DrawingContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653182.aspx) and push (via [PushTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingcontext.pushtransform.aspx)) a 90° clockwise RotateTransform onto it,
3. draw the GlyphRun to the DrawingContext.

A simple way to get an appropriate DrawingContext would be to override [UIElement.OnRender](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.onrender.aspx).

Note: GlyphRun's constructor has 13 arguments, but the last 6 may be null :-)

Comment: Interesting. This is definitely something I would like to look into further.

Comment: Great. I'd love to hear whether you were successful with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextBlock Width="7" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        S<LineBreak/>
        t<LineBreak/>
        a<LineBreak/>
        c<LineBreak/>
        k
</TextBlock>
```